# locate together with find

Tags: find, locate

I want to take all files from the current directory and give them to "locate" to check if they are elsewhere.
So I started with

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "libd*" -exec locate {} ';'
```

But this does not work because find returns the names in a form like "./libdrm.so" and locate does not work with the leading dot. So I thought locate -b should help:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "libd*" -exec locate -b {} ';'
```

Unfortunately, locate -b ./libdrm.so does not work, I regard this as a bug. So I tried it with basename:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "libd*" -exec locate \`basename {}\` ';'
```

This does not work either because `basename {}` is resolved first and the result is "-exec locate '{}' ';'".

Any idea how I can pass "locate `basename {}`" to the exec?

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to search for files in the actual folder you also could use

```
locate libd*
```

or something like as follows, but does not make much sense.

```
ls libd* | xargs locate
locate $(ls libd*)
```

If you want to use find, you also could use `*` instead of `.`, but I also would quote the `{}`.

```
find * -maxdepth 1 -name "libd*" -exec locate "{}" ';'
```

Lastly, if you want to include dot-files, aka hidden files with glob.

```
shopt -s dotglob
find * -maxdepth 1 -name "libd*" -exec locate "{}" ';'
shopt -u dotglob
```

Comment: I like this `ls libd* | xargs locate` nice combo!

Comment: why does "find -exec" return all names with a leading "./" whereas "find * -exec" does not?

Comment: `find` without a starting point uses `.` as default. If you use `*`, it will expand due to shell glob before the find command starts. So find will search on the expanded glob results.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "libd*" | sed 's^\./^^' | locate -
```

This solution for sure is not elegant, but it works for me – `sed 's^\./^^'` simply deletes “./” from the beginning of each line.

If you want to use multiple command in `-exec`, do it this way:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "libd*" -exec bash -c 'basename $1 | locate -' {} \;
```

Comment: Use `cut -d/ -f2` it's easier to read.

Comment: @waltinator That's a matter of taste, but using a different delimiter is a good idea here – have `^` for fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "libd*" -exec sh -c 'for f; do locate "${f##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "libd*" -printf '%f\0' | while read -rd '' f; do locate "$f"; done
```

Comment: I think the "while read" trick is very useful, thanks. This way one can concatenate many commands.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "libd*" | sed -r 's/^\.\///' | xargs locate
```

`sed -r 's/^\.\///'`: removes the `./` from the `find` command